# iOS hardware-backed key attestation

Tags: cryptography, ios, remote-attestation

In android there is a way of knowing if the public key from a key pair was generated inside TEE and is, therefore, hardware-backed (https://source.android.com/security/keystore/attestation). I cannot find a way to do that in iOS. Does anyone know if there is a way?

Comment: Maybe someone is interested about the progress (if any) on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914154/ios-hardware-backed-key-attestation